# Cannot UPDATE a view that uses a join

Tags: oracle, view

```
create view  drums 
as 
select emp.sno,emp.name,emps.sal,emps.deptno 
from emplys emp  
   inner join employees emps  on emp.sno=emps.sno 
where emp.deptno<5;
```

when I use this

```
update drum set sal=111111 where name='aravind'
```

command it show error as

> ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table

Comment: Can you give the structure of both tables and their primary keys? You can only use the update with a view if the view has all the key fields in the fields that it returns.

Comment: how to see the structure of the both table??

Answer (score 1):

*<sub>Wiki answer generated from comments on the question by [miracle173](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/2047/miracle173):</sub>*

---

Here is the [error message manual](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ERRMG/e1500.htm#sthref856) and here is an explanation of [key preserved table](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:548422757486) by Tom Kyte.

There are [updatable views](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/views.htm#ADMIN11782) but there are some restrictions.

Related Stack Overflow question:

- [Updating a Join View without getting Non Key-Preserved Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18644258/updating-a-join-view-without-getting-non-key-preserved-error)